# How to pin Widths Equally to some UIViews with NSLayoutConstraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

How can I pin more than two UIViews with Widths Equally using NSLayoutConstraints?

Right now, I'm using the following code and I can't pin more than two UIViews:

```
for (int i = 0; i < column.count; i++) {
    NSString *horizontalFormat = @"H:|[view1][view2(==view1)]|";
    NSDictionary *views;
    if (i < column.count - 1) {
        views  = @{
                   @"view1": column[i],
                   @"view2": column[i + 1]
                   };
    }else{
        views  = @{
                   @"view1": column[i - 1],
                   @"view2": column[i]
                   };
    }
    NSArray * horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:horizontalFormat
                                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:views];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you editing this question because you still have not learned the answer?

Comment: @matt I got a solution using storyboard but I didn't get a solution programmatically

Comment: So what's the goal? You want to lay out `n` views in a row so that they are all the same width / height and all touching one another?

Comment: @matt Yes, to make a dynamic table, like an Excel sheet. I'm sorry for edited the question, this project was closed long time ago but this week was opened again.

Comment: Okay, so may I ask first of all why you wouldn't use a UICollectionView? And in the second place, if you don't want to use a UICollectionView, why you don't use a UIStackView? I mean, I can certainly write you the code that does what you describe, but why, when there are excellent tools for doing it?

Comment: @matt Ok, you are right. When I started to write that app, UIStackView didn't exist. Thank you for the advice !!

Comment: Okay, cool. Anyway, I've written the code that does what you describe so I'll put it in an answer for you. But seriously, let UIStackView do this for you! It generates _exactly_ the same constraints but it does it automatically!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example. All views are generated in the code, so just copy this code right into a UIViewController (e.g. into its `viewDidLoad`) and run it:

```
UIView* v1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
v1.layer.borderWidth = 2;
v1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:v1];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:
 @[[v1.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:100],
   [v1.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor],
   [v1.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40],
   ]];
NSInteger n = 6; // change this number as desired
NSMutableArray* marr = [NSMutableArray new];
[marr addObject:v1];
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    UIView* v = [[UIView alloc] init];
    v.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    v.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:v];
    [marr addObject:v];
}
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    UIView* v = marr[i];
    UIView* prev = marr[i-1];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:
     @[[v.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v1.topAnchor],
       [v.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v1.bottomAnchor],
       [v.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:prev.trailingAnchor],
       [v.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v1.widthAnchor]
       ]];
}
UIView* v = marr[n-1];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:
 @[[v.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor]
  ]];
```

Comment: Sure, no problem. Just wanted to show the basic technique.

Answer (score 2):

Each NSLayoutConstraint can only relate two views, but nothing is stopping you from adding additional constraints.  E.g:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:column[i-1] attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:column[i] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplied:1.f constant:0.f];

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:column[i+1] attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:column[i] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplied:1.f constant:0.f];
```

If you add these two constraints, the "columns" at i-1, i, and i+1 will now all have equal widths.